# Do I actually need 2 upload forms, 1 for single images and 1 for many images or can I just use 1 multi image form?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I have 2 upload forms and 2 functions, `uploadImage();` and `uploadAlbum();`. I have been wondering if I could remove the single image form and use the multi image form for both cases. If only 1 image is selected in the multi image form, a single image would be uploaded and if more than 1 images are uploaded, an album would be uploaded.

That would make the upload view look better since it won't have 2 identical upload forms and it would only require 1 function on the back-end that would determine whether it's a single image or an album based on the amount of images uploaded.

I don't really see any downsides to it but I wanted to make sure before reworking the code.

My upload view:

```
<form class='uploadForm' action="{{ route('imageUpload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="name">Image Name</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="name" placeholder="Image Name">

        <label for="description">Image Description</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">

        <input type="file" name="image"> {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class='Submit' type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>

    <form class='uploadForm' action="{{ route('albumUpload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="albumName">Album Name</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="albumName" placeholder="Album Name">

        <label for="albumDescription">Image Description</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="albumDescription" placeholder="Description">

        <input type="file" name='files[]' multiple> {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class='Submit' type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
```

My `uploadImage()` and `uploadeAlbum()` functions:

```
public function uploadAlbum(Request $request){
        $name = $request['albumName'];
        $description = $request['albumDescription'];
        $tag = $request['tags'];
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
        $files = $request->file('files');
        $path = 'storage/uploads/albums/'.$name;

        $fileOriginalName = $files[0]->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileOriginalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $files[0]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);

        $album = new Album();
        $album->name = $name;
        $album->description = $description;
        $album->user_id = $userId;
        $album->thumbnail = $fileNameToStore;

        $album->save();
        $album->tags()->attach($tag);

        if(!File::exists($path)) {
            File::makeDirectory(public_path($path));
        }

        if (is_array($files) || is_object($files)){
            foreach ($files as $file){
                $fileOriginalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileOriginalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);

                $file->storeAs('public/uploads/albums/'.$name, $fileNameToStore);
                $file->storeAs('public/uploads/albums/'.$name.'/thumbnails/', $fileNameToStore);

                $thumbnailImage = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/albums/'.$name.'/thumbnails/'.$fileNameToStore)->fit(400, 400, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });

                $thumbnailImage->save();

                $albumImage = new AlbumImage();
                $albumImage->file_name = $fileNameToStore;
                $albumImage->album_id = $album->id;

                $albumImage->save();
            }
        }
        return redirect()->route('albums');
    }
```

---

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'description' => 'max:120|nullable',
            'image' => 'required'
        ]);

        $name = $request['name'];
        $description = $request['description'];
        $tag = $request['tags'];
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
        $file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);

        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/specificImages/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/miniImages/',$fileNameToStore);

        $thumbnail = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$fileNameToStore )->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $thumbnail->save();

        $specificImage = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$fileNameToStore )->resize(2000, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $specificImage->save();

        $miniImage = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$fileNameToStore )->fit(200, 200, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $miniImage->save();

        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->description = $description;
        $image->user_id = $userId;
        $image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

        $image->save();
        $image->tags()->attach($tag);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible of course. You would have to use the field that allows multiple

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

When submitting the form you can check for if the `$_POST['files']` array contains only one file. If it does, you can use the logic of a single file (image) and if it contains more you can use the logic of multiple files (album).

When you have this working you can also merge the majority of your logic and split it into multiple functions. One would be called with a `foreach`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what part of my logic should I split into functions?

Comment: Use single form. If only once image is upload it will be image if multiple it will consider as album. You are right.

Comment: That is another question, so if you need an answer on that too, please open another question. Generally speaking you can create a function that processes and saves the files, and another function that handles multiple of them. The latter would call the former.